# Dynamic Requires section in RPM based on installation environment

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

On my setup, where RPM will be installed, will have a file below:

```
#cat /etc/setup-details
environment=QA
#
```

Now, if environment is QA, i want below Requires:

Requires: my-qa-rpm

If environment is dev, i want below Requires:

Requires: my-dev-rpm

How to achieve dynamic Requires in RPM based on environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such a thing as dynamic requires that you are requesting. The only workaround is creating two packages (each with proper `Requres:`) then install the correct package by checking the value in the file (via bash script).